# nodejs tls module for server-client communication without browser

Tags: node.js, ssl

I wish to securely send messages back and forth between a client and a remote server (just an IP address and a port) using nodejs. The client runs a local .js file and does not use a browser. I have tried to do so using the node TLS module (https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html).

The handshake works perfectly fine, but I can not manage to send a message from the server to the client. My current code is:

client.js

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  host: <server IP address>,
  port: <port number>,
  key: fs.readFileSync('client.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.crt'),
  checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
    return undefined;
  }  
};

const client = tls.connect(options, function(){
  if (client.authorized) {
    console.log("Connection authorized");
  } else {
    console.log("Connection not authorized: " + conn.authorizationError)
  }
  process.stdin.pipe(client);
  process.stdin.resume();
  client.emit('data','message')
});

client.setEncoding('utf8');

client.addListener('data', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});

client.on('end', () => {
  server.close();
});
```

server.js

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.crt'), 
  requestCert: true, 
  rejectUnauthorized: true  
};

const server = tls.createServer(options, function(socket){
  console.log('server connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  socket.pipe(socket);
  socket.emit('data','I am the server')
});

server.listen(<port number>,function(){
  console.log('listening')

})

server.on('connection',function(client){
  console.log('client connected')
  client.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

The server does output 'client connected' but does not do anything with the client.on() part, and I can not find another way to make the server listen for messages from the client. Is there a way to use the tls module so that I can make the client and server interact based on the messages they send and receive? Again, I do not want to use a browser.

Comment: To send data between the two endpoints, you need to use `socket.write()` which will trigger the `data` event on the other side. You're sending raw data, so if you want to structure the messages in any way you have to implement that yourself. You should probably get rid of `socket.pipe(socket)`, which echoes back data sent _by_ the client _to_ the client.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. I would like to connect to the server with two different clients. Is there a way to specifiy on the server side, to which client it should write data? If I want to send a message to client A that may not be sent to client B for example.

Comment: For each client connection, the `connection` event will fire (FWIW, you now have an explicit listener for `connection`, but the function that you pass to `tls.createServer()` does the same (it's an implicit listener for the same event). The argument you receive in the event handler represents the client connection, so if you send something to a specific client, you should call `write` on the socket that represents the client you want to send a message to (however, how you can distinguish between clients is something you need to implement yourself)

Comment: Thank you, your answers helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The comments by @robertklep helped me solve my issue. Delete the socket.pipe(socket) line on the server side, and on the client side just use socket.write() to send a message to the server. This can be received by a socket.on('data') instance on the server side. Also, to interact with multiple clients, you can write something like:

```
var socket = {}; 

const server = tls.createServer(options, function(s){
  client=s.getPeerCertificate().subject.CN
  socket[client] = s;
  socket[client].setEncoding('utf8');
  socket[client].write('welcome')

  for (key in socket){
    socket[key].write('new client connected')
  }

  socket[client].on('data',function(data){
    socket[client].write('data received')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a `Set` for notifying new connections of being connected makes more sense. An object being added to a set must be unique to the set if it is to be added. You can also just use `socket.server._connectionKey` to determine what client it is, don't have to mess around with getting the peer certificate.

```
var sockets = new Set();

const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
  console.log('server connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');

  var sock_set_len = sockets.size; //get size of sockets set
  var key = socket.server._connectionKey;

  sockets.add(key); //attempt to add socket to connection list

  if(sock_set_len < sockets.size) { //if the socket _connectionKey is unique, it will be added, and will be treated as a new connection here.
    socket.write("you are connected...");
  }

  socket.on('data',function(data){
    socket.write(data);
  })

  socket.on('end', socket.end);
});
```

On a side note, I created a package to handle sockets with Obj-C iOS, taking into account the latest (iOS 13) TLS restrictions imposed by Apple:

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets

I used a Node JS TLS server to receive connections, a variation of the `echo server` example in the Node JS docs