# How can a nodejs TLS server send a message to all connected clients?

Tags: node.js, ssl, server, client

If two clients are connecting to a server using tls.connect(), the server can communicate with the client that connects, through

```
const server = tls.createServer(options, function(
    socket.write('hello!')
});
```

How can I make the server send this 'hello' message to all connected clients when a new client connects?

Comment: I guess you are looking for a broadcast option ?
socket.broadcast('hello!')

Comment: @tailhour yes. Do you know how this is done in the tls module? Also, it would be nice to be able to send a message to client A and client B, but not to client C.

Comment: Not quite sure about broadcast option into TLS, need to take a look. About other question you can store each of your connections separately and reuse it after that.
sockets = {
  'user1',
  'user2'
}
sockets.user1.write 
.....

Comment: Fixed it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074244/nodejs-tls-module-for-server-client-communication-without-browser?noredirect=1#comment75195658_44074244

Answer (score 0):

You can store the sockets in a array and create a function to send a message to each one when a new connection is created.

Some like this:

```
const sockets: TLSSocket[] = [];

const server = tls.createServer(options)
    .on('secureConnection', (socket) => {
        sockets.push(socket);

        broadcastMessage('hello from server');

        socket.on('data', (message) => {
            console.log('message: ', message);
        });

        socket.on('close', (socket) => {
            const socketIndex = sockets.findIndex(socket => socket)
            sockets.splice(socketIndex, 1);
        })
    })
    .listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log(`Server running at ${hostname}:${port}`);
    });

function broadcastMessage(message: string): void {
    sockets.forEach(socket => {
        socket.emit('data', JSON.stringify(message));
    });
};
```